# Google Colab VM - Export Image to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I have been using both Google Colab and GCP VM instances for training some deep learning models.

With Google Colab, I haven't had any issues so far with installing a wide variety of deep learning packages that I explore as part of my work. With GCP VM instances though (even using the pre-configured Deep Learning VMs offered by Google), I frequently run into issues.
I was wondering if there is a way to export the Google Colab VM as an image to Google Cloud Storage, and then launch an instance in GCP using this image.

I tried searching online for this, but I couldn't find anything.
Is this do-able? Or, are there any other alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: any progress on this? year and a half later?